# How does this program works and executes?

Tags: java

```
class Average 
{ 
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        double nums[] = {10.1, 11.2, 12.3, 13.4, 14.5}; 
        // Assigning some values to the Array 
        double result = 0; 
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<5; i++) 
            result = result + nums[i];
        System.out.println("Average is " + result / 5);
    }
}
```

How this Program Works. Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: It's all [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html).

Comment: There is no one to help me :(

Answer (score 0):

You have created a double array called nums with these values in it {10.1, 11.2, 12.3, 13.4, 14.5}. Then you created a variable result and assigned 0 to it. Then a for loop for which condition is i<5 which means it is going to run 5 times starting from 0 as value of i is 0. Inside the for loop, you are adding value of each element to the result variable.

Basically, you did summation of all elements of array and stored the result into result variable.

And then at the end, you are printing out the average by dividing 5 which is length of the array.

Answer (score 0):

This is how your iteration works:
when

```
    i=0  result = 0+10.1
    i=1  result = 10.1+11.2
    i=2  result = 21.3+12.3
    i=3  result = 33.6+13.4
    i=4  result = 47.0+14.5 
         result=  61.5
         
         61.5/5 
         = 12.29
```